# Object must implement IComparable?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class file;

```
class testList : List<exampleNC>
{
   // within the class, using a function, I add stuff to the list.
}

class exampleNC
{
   private string s,p,c; private bool a;
}
```

Now, I have the following code which throws the error "Atleast one object must implement IComparable"

```
if (!list.OrderBy(l => l).SequenceEqual(tmp.OrderBy(l => l)))
{
   list = tmp;

   updated = true;
}
```

Both `list` and `tmp` are the EXACT same CLASSES aka`testList : List<exampleNC>`

What I am trying to do really is check whether `private bool` a inside `exampleNC` has been updated aka checking my original list (`!list`) against a new list (`tmp`).

Comment: Can you show the callstack?

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: Let me show it now...

How can I add a IComparable to my existing class testList?

Comment: It's not `testList` that needs to implement `IComparable`. It's `exampleNC`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `OrderBy` to sort a collection of `exampleNC` without telling how to compare two instances of `exampleNC`. That's what your error is about.

Make your `exampleNC` implement `IComparable<exampleNC>` to make the error message go away, or choose to order using just one of the properties instead of the entire object:

```
.OrderBy(l => l.a)
```

But that will most likely result in incorrect results anyway, unless `exampleNC` implements `IEquatable<exampleNC>`, which would make `SequanceEqual` work as expected. Without that it will perform reference equality, which most likely is not what you're looking for.

Comment: I can't do .a as its a private variable?

Comment: Well, then you have to either make it public or implement `IComparable` (+ `IEquatable` to make `SequanceEqual` work).

Comment: Why is `a` a private variable that you want to order by, in a class that doesn't implement `IComparable`? Either the class should help you compare objects of its types, the class should give you sufficient information to compare objects of its types, or you shouldn't care about comparing them. At least one of those three things not being the case is a design flaw.

Comment: Im going to take the easy way out and make it all public

Comment: It will make the error go, but you'll still most likely get incorrect results from `SequanceEqual`. You should reconsider changing your design (or maybe think about it for the first time?).

Comment: Incidentally, note that if you'd wanted to e.g. order by `a` but with `s` breaking ties then you'd be able to either make the `OrderBy` lambda complicated enough to handle that logic or else use `ThenBy` after the `OrderBy`

Comment: is it if (!list.OrderBy(l => l.a).SequenceEqual(tmp.OrderBy(l => l.a)))

I am just trying to compare each item in the list from another updated same list, see if a changed in each item, if so, update the list totally.

Comment: You're not entirely correct in saying that you need to implement `IEquatable<exampleNC>` for `SequenceEqual` to work. It suffices to override `object.Equals`. Of course, if you've done so then you're probably as well to implement `IEquatable` which will be trivial then, and give a performance and self-documentation benefit. And if you do that you should always override `object.Equals` to match (and of course override `GetHashCode`. Alternatively, if one can't modify the class one can use the form of `SequenceEquals` that takes an `IEqualityComparer` argument.

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot about `object.Equals`. That's a possibility.